# Is it possible to access the Go To XY Tool in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I've looked around I but can't seem to find a coclass/interface that would allow me to access it. I know I could make something similar but I'm curious about interacting with the built-in tool to save some work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to popup the existing dialog programmatically then you can find most commands here:  [ArcMap IDs](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/shared/desktop/reference/arcmapids.htm).

The one you want appears to be:  [ControlsMapGoToCommand](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriControls/ControlsMapGoToCommand.htm).  Normally I'd be concerned that a Controls* object would only work with an ArcEngine (map) control, but the doc's say it works for ArcMap as well.

To execute you:
- get the ICommandItem from IDocument.CommandBars.Find().
- call ICommandItem.Execute().

[EDIT]
If you want to programmatically pan/zoom to a location then see the following sample code:  [ControlsCommandsPanZoomCommands](https://github.com/esri/arcobjects-sdk-community-samples/tree/master/Net/Controls//ControlsCommandsPanZoomCommands)

Comment: That could certainly be of use to me, what I'm more curious about though is if I can access the inner methods/properties of the tool. For example to set the lat/long fields and execute the "go to" functionality programmatically.

Comment: So you don't want to use the tool per se, you just want to achieve the same effect - you want to programmatically pan|zoom a frame to a given location.  Correct ?

Comment: Well since we will often use the tool to center the map frame before exporting multiple maps in a consistent location, I do want to use the tool (as well as some of its other features). But the process of entering values into its fields often involves identifying/copying/pasting, so I'm wanting to enter values into the tool programmatically for when the center point needs to be adjusted many times. Then the tool could still be an option to the user as before.

Comment: "for when the center point needs to be adjusted many times"
Can you provide a user story explaining that ?  That is fill in the rest of, "as a user I want to ..." a series of steps.  Panning in code is one of the simpler things to do, not worth trying to use the tool if the code knows where you want to pan to.

Comment: It is, I'm being a bit unclear but I can simplify it by saying I just want to enter values into the tool programmatically (ex: from coords of where the user clicks among other ways). I could make a tool from scratch that does everything I need it to but the existing tool already does it all (and probably faster) except for how the values are entered. So I wanted to extend its functionality just a bit if possible.

Comment: Look at the sample code link I posted.  It has the full code for a pan tool.  It doesn't have the popup, but that's easy enough to add.  From what you've posted, I'd extend the sample code as needed a create a new tool.  You can use the ESRI Object Browser to look at the interfaces the ControlsMapGoToCommand implements, again basic with no mechanism to plug into it.